# Compile GNU C project with C++

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, gnu

I just joined a project and there's a bunch of code (which has been written by 4 or 5 different people over the last 5 years).  It's all C at this point, but I want to migrate the project to C++ in order to take advantage of OOP.

Step 1 will be to simply leave all the existing code in place and just selectively convert very small pieces of the functionality to be object oriented.

It's my understanding that C can be compiled by C++, but maybe I'm wrong about this.

So, before I invest a whole lot of time in trying to actually do it, am I likely to be able to get the existing C code to compile using C++ relatively easily?

Or, is this likely to involve a massive migration before it will work?

What factors affect the complexity of the task I'm proposing?

So to be clear - I'm *not* asking how big a project it will be to convert all of the code to objects, functions to methods, etc - but rather, just what I'm likely to face getting the existing C code to compile using the C++ compiler instead of the C compiler.

Thanks in advance - I look forward to any help/guidance you can provide.

**EDIT**

Sounds like it's really not a good idea.  I always thought of c++ as an expansion of C, but it sounds like they're different enough that this is not an advisable path.  Ultimately, I wasn't thinking of them as Different Languages, and was hoping that c++ was more backwards compatible with c than it sounds like it is. My initial searching made it look like people had done it to varying degrees of success, but the responses here make me think I should really just consider them to be two different languages.  Thanks!

Comment: Often, C code will compile well without modification with a C++ compiler, but whether it can be guaranteed, I don't know.

Comment: In fact, most substantial C code isn’t valid C++ (different keywords, different casting rules which will impact most uses of `malloc` …) but can often be ported mechanically.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to take existing code that you know little to nothing about and compile it under a different language?

Comment: @owacoder: identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. Even **iff** it compiles does not mean it will run the same.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. While you of course can port C code to C++, do not expect to have the same semantics for the same syntax. You have to know both languages well enough to port. Not to mention that a proper port worth its name will use the features the language provides. Thus, often a re-implementation is often the better way (yet one the bosses understand muss less often - because they don't know the languages).

Comment: The first step would be to confer with the other developers and make sure that they all want to change the language of the project

Comment: I don't think bottom-up is good practice. I'd rather do it top-down: use C++ to layout the architecture and reuse business logic written in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I always thought of c++ as an expansion of C, but it sounds like they're different enough that this is not an advisable path.

C++ is **not** an expansion of C. They are completely different languages. Compiling C code with C++ is not simply enabling "OO-mode". When you compile anything but trivial C code with a C++ compiler, you are potentially opening yourself up to a world of hurt due to the differences between the two languages.

> am I likely to be able to get the existing C code to compile using C++ relatively easily?

Again, you have a fundamental misunderstanding -- C++ is **not** some extended version of C. They are different languages.

The best course of action is to slowly migrate your code to C++, but using *two* different compilers. Compile the C code with a C compiler, and compile the C++ code with a C++ compiler. It is not a challenging feat since any modern compiler suite (like GCC and clang) can compile both C and C++ very well.

> is this likely to involve a massive migration before it will work?

If you intend to convert your code to C++, then yes.

One thing is worth mentioning: if you are compiling your C code with a C++ compiler, and calling it programming in C++, you're missing the spirit of the C++ development environment. If you're programming in C++, but using C code with very little OO, then what's the point of using C++? Just skip the overhead of OO and code in C. Using a C++ compiler is not some magic process that will instantly make your code better.

Comment: Thank you SevenBits. This is exactly what I wanted to find out. As far as your last paragraph goes, I was not imagining that it was any kind of magic process. Rather, I was hoping to be able to migrate the project to an object oriented framework piece-by-piece. In other words, start by getting the existing C to compile with C++, and then begin designing new code (as objects) to begin the process of migrating the procedural C code to a more object oriented design. This post has made it abundantly clear that they are totally separate languages and that this approach will simply not work. Thanks!

Comment: Right. I would migrate it to C++ one source file at a time. Compile new C++ files with the C++ compiler, and any leftover files should be compiled with the C compiler. Then you can use the linker to combine everything into one application, library, whatever.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into this further.  Thanks again for all the help everyone - this is exactly what I was hoping to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look [here](http://david.tribble.com/text/cdiffs.htm) to get a list of (possible) issues.

What I did in the past for a C to C++ mgration was to leave the C code working as it should (C code compiled with a C compiler) and - in parallel - rewrite the code from scratch in C++.

Comment: That link is a bit outdated. C++11 added quite some changes/additions to C++, as much as C99 did for C. C11 changes less, but still changed some aspects. The statement of yours is a good idea, though.